# Free code quality / code coverage plugin or service for GitHub

Tags: gratis, java

I am looking for a plugin or service that I can connect to the **GitHub** repository so that:

checked the quality of the code,
generate code coverage reports in the project
The project is **Open Source** in Java, Spring Boot and **Plugin / Serwis must be free**.